# promisses inside loop in npm Q

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I am implementing a code to save all tags to db. I am rejecting the promise if even 1 error is caught. Below code for reference.

```
module.exports = {

    save_tag: function(tag, id) {

        //Some logic to validate a tag goes here

        return db.save(tag,id);  //db.save is a promise;
    },
    save_tags: function(tags, post_id) {

        var def = Q.defer();

        _.forEach(tags, function(tag, key) {
            self.save_tag(tag, post_id).then(null, def.reject);
        });
        return def.promise;
    }
};
```

I would like to know how can I resolve the promise in `save_tags` function if all tags are saved successfully in `save_tag` function.

I am using npm Q library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module.exports = {
    save_tag: function(tag, id) {
        return db.save(tag,id);  // db.save is a promise;
    },
    save_tags: function(tags, post_id) {
        var savedTags = _.map(tags, function(tag) {
            return self.save_tag(tag, post_id);
        });
        return Q.all(savedTags);
    }
};
```

https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseall

Comment: As easy as it could have been... Thankyou very much... My life would be at peace now...

Comment: Your life peace is enviably easy to achieve. ;)

Comment: Just wanted to make a small note here. If you want to run each tag irrespective of pass or fail, Use Q.allSettled instead of Q.all

Answer (score -1):

```
self.save_tag(tag, post_id).then(function _returnOK(){
  //def.resolve();
}).fail(function _returnFail(){
  //def.reject();
});
```

I think it will resolve.